# Label.Text does not exist to the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I receive an error message lblHoName content does not exist to the current content.I try to delete fibe.aspx page and added it again  file but nothing... I try to remove it complete and also nothing..

what else i should try in order to solve the problem?

```
<%@Page Language="C#"AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FIBE.aspx.cs" Inherits="_FIBE" %>


public partial class _FIBE : System.Web.UI.Page
{
```

In my aspx,

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHoName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

In my code behind ,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    lblHoName.Text = Session["HotelName"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: are you using namespace in any of the other .cs files ..? also `CodeFile="FIBE.aspx.cs` change `CodeFile` to `CodeBehind=`

Comment: Is that first line of markup **really** what you have? Seems like you're missing some whitespace.

Comment: @MethodMan when i changed the CodeFile="FIBE.aspx.cs to CodeBehind= FIBE.aspx.cs  that error happen 'Could not load type '_FIBE'."

Comment: @mason no i am not missing i checked it now

Comment: are you manually creating the file..? if so delete it and use the IDE to create the new file

Comment: @hashim In that case, you need to learn how the language works. You need whitespace. That first line should read: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FIBE.aspx.cs" Inherits="_FIBE" %>`

Comment: @mason   i know what u mean i remove whit spaces check the question again now

Comment: Now you need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You don't have enough code here, so you need to have the minimal amount of code required to duplicate your problem.

Comment: @mason   www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx  this the website you can check i

Comment: @hashim No, I'm not checking out your site. Questions on Stack Overflow **must be** self contained and not rely on links to external sites. Follow the directions I provided above for creating an MCVE.

Comment: i @MethodMan i can not understand you well but i delete the page and add another page with the same code .

Comment: @hashim what do you mean that you can't understand.. do you know how to add new items to the project..? if so then select add new items then select new web page.. do not do this manually

Comment: @mason ok i'll edit my code now i'll make it helpfully more than this . right now

Comment: @MethodMan now i did  this manually add new item then add new web form, what you want to do .?

Comment: update your question and show us what the aspx file heading looks like..come on now.. ...please show a little bit more effort..

Comment: also `lblHoName="Hello";` is an object.. you need to do 
`lblHoName.Text = "Hello";` I would seriously recommend reading up on some basic `C# Tutorials for Beginners` also if you are going to show code examples in your codebehind.. please post the actual codebehind in your updated question

Comment: @MethodMan sorry i forget to write property text sorry , i edit the last update with the same code in my project well.

Comment: where do you initialize this `Session["HotelName"]` I would personally use `HttpContext.Current.Session["HotelName"] = string.Empty` Initialize that in the `OnSessionStart` in the global.asax page then check for the (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["HotelName"]` once again you need to show a heck of a lot more code than what you are showing.. `remember We can't see what you see on your screen` so please provide all relevant code that pertains to your question

Comment: @MethodMan  ok i provide it now in the question

Comment: @hashim please read the documentation on how to ask a question.. if you are not sure in regards to how to post code please open up another tab and look at some other C# questions on stackoverflow.com to see how others post code examples in their question. we do not have time to be spoon fed and it's not that difficult to post full code that pertains to your question.. you can't assign something to another when you have not initially assigned the value to that particular object.. please show where you have initialized the assignment of the session variable..

Comment: `lblHoName.Text = Session["HotelName"].ToString();` this will always be `null` because you never show were you changed the value initially for example it will compile if you do the following 
`Session["HotelName"] = "I am hard headed";`
`lblHoName.Text = Session["HotelName"].ToString();` good luck @hashim I would seriously suggest that you take the time out to do a google search on `C# Basics Tutorials`

Comment: @MethodMan i know what you mean of-course i initials the session before i use it with the label .but i see i don't need provide it   to solve this problem .

Comment: @MethodMan my problem i can not find this control like i write in the question

Comment: you need to read through the comments and try what was suggested your problem from what I can see is in the codfile= line that should be codebehind.. I am sorry but I cannot waste anymore time on this since you are not willing to do what's right

Answer (score 0):

Change "PageLanguage" to "Page Language" in first line.

Comment: i changed it but nothing happened check the question again now i edit it

Comment: I think, you don't have enough code in this question. There is no error in these lines, something is missing in question.

Comment: link, which is provided by you, showing another error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Your session is expired. So, this is showing an error

Comment: check session is null or not before this line

Comment: lblHoName.Text = Session["HotelName"].ToString(); this the line with error ok not from the Session from the control not exist .

Comment: @hashim this is a simple fix if you would initialize it properly and then show the code for where you initialize it ..then debug the code to make sure that the `lblHoName` is actually set.. what is the value at design time..?